# Reading in points from a file

Tags: matlab

I have a txt file in which each row has the x, y ,z coordinates of the point. seperated by space.I want to read points from this txt file and store it as a matrix in matlab of the form [Pm_1 Pm_2 ... Pm_nmod] where each Pm_n is a point .Could someone help me with this?

I have to actually enter it into a code which accepts the model as :

"model - matrix with model points, [Pm_1 Pm_2 ... Pm_nmod]"

Comment: If you write `[Pm_1 Pm_2 ... Pm_nmod]` out would it look like `[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]` assuming your 3 points were `(1,2,3)`,`(4,5,6)`,`(7,8,9)`?

Comment: I guess not .In the previous version I used (with importdata/dlmread) it uses mxGetM to check the model and complains saying:-"Dimension of model points must be 3."

Comment: You need to explain your question in more detail. Here you're saying the dimension must be 3, and before you stated you wanted an `npoints`x1 matrix.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion .Well thts what I thought initially .But when I debugged ,read the error message and checked the code.I think I was wrong in saying nptsx1 matrix.If its still unclear let me know.

Comment: So you need a 3D matrix? Isn't that what you get from `importdata`/`dlmread`?

Comment: Well I guess but I think i'll need to transpose because importdata gives me nx3 and I think mxGetm checks the rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [`importdata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/importdata.html) heavily for this. It reads all kinds of formats ; I normally use other methods like [`dlmread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/dlmread.html) only if `importdata` doesn't work.

Usage is as simple as `M = importdata('data.txt');`

Comment: I already tried dlmread(dlmread(file,' ')).My point is it comes out as  npointsx3 matrix whereas what I want is nptsx1 matrix with each point containing the x,y,z co-ordinates.

Comment: Yep importdata gives me the same thing too :-)

Comment: I just read your comment. Do you want each element to hold 3 numbers? Then it's not your "ordinary" MATLAB matrix --- you can use a `cell array`. I'll explain further if this is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
 load -ascii data.txt
```

That creates a matrix called `data' in your workspace whose rows contain the coordinates.

You can find all the details of the conversion in the [documentation for the load command](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/load.html).